# Chef; The easiest way to run single cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I'd love to know what is the best way to run single or multiple cookbooks within VM, and see what's going on.

VM should be Virtualbox instance and vagrant could be used.

I could do something like in `Vagrantfile` if I simple use vagrant.

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = ["site-cookbooks", "cookbooks"]
      chef.add_recipe ‘my_cookbook' 
    end
end
```

Any ideas for more easy way to simply run cookbooks?

Answer (score 0):

What you show is one option but the usual route people go is to use Test Kitchen instead.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @coderanger you are best advised to learn how test kitchen works

- http://kitchen.ci/

It comes bundled with the Chef development kit

- https://docs.chef.io/about_chefdk.html
- https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk

## Example

First generate a cookbook called "demo"

```
chef generate cookbook demo
```

This will automatically create a test kitchen file that uses vagrant (under the hood and hidden away) to run chef against a choice of Ubuntu or CentOS. This enables you to verify your cookbooks' logic against multiple target platforms.

```
$ cd demo
$ kitchen list
Instance             Driver   Provisioner  Verifier  Transport  Last Action    Last Error
default-ubuntu-1604  Vagrant  ChefZero     Inspec    Ssh        <Not Created>  <None>
default-centos-73    Vagrant  ChefZero     Inspec    Ssh        <Not Created>  <None>
```

So... How to run your Chef cookbook against an ubuntu VM?

```
$ kitchen converge default-ubuntu-1604
```

But running cookbooks is only where it gets started. More powerfully you can write Inspec tests to prove your cookbook is working as expected. Well worth learning.